# Preloading Cocos2D textures when a standard UIKit UIView is visible

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uikit, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

My app uses Cocos2D for animation and 2D rendering, but the "game lobby" (that's not what it is, but for all intents and purposes) is all standard `UIView`/`UIKit` code.

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that has its main view set in the XIB file as an `EAGLView`.  When I put all the Cocos loading code into `viewDidLoad`, everything works as expected, except that there is a 1-2 second freeze while Cocos loads all my textures.

I have about 20 textures that I preload into the `CCSpriteFrameCache` before running my scene - so my animations are smooth immediately.

I tried to move this texture loading code to my view controller's `init` method -- but when I try this, Cocos crashes, seemingly because there is no OpenGL context to work with.

What I want to do is, while displaying a `UIViewController`'s main view (and not blocking the main thread), I'd like to load textures in the background, and then when finished, transition between that `UIView` and the OpenGL `EAGLView`.

I am aware that there is an `addImageAsync:` call in Cocos now, so it's really just a matter of somehow "passing around an offscreen EAGLView/EAGLContext" that I can eventually stick into Cocos when I am ready to display that view.

Does anyone have any pointers on an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to create a separate EAGLContext, using which I would load the textures.  That EAGLContext needed to share a EAGLSharegroup with the actual GL view that I used to render the content.  So the steps worked like this:

1. Create/load/show my UI View
2. Create my to-be-used EAGLView
3. Snag the EAGLSharegroup off that EAGLView
4. Create a EAGLContext using that sharegroup
5. Load my textures using that EAGLContext
6. Switch my UIView to the EAGLView
7. Textures are loaded and available

Comment: If you can get the final context at the start anyways, why not just load the textures directly into it? Why create the secondary one?

Comment: Apple warns us to have 1 context per thread.  I was doing my loading on a background thread, hence the need for a new context.  Good shout, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ah right, if it's on a different thread, then this sounds familiar.